# Why is this error occuring in my leetcode problem ?88. Merge Sorted Array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9

CODE

```
class Solution {
public:
    void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) {
   // int size1=m+n;
   // int size2=nums2.size();
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    vector<int> v;
    while(i<m || j<n)
    {
        if(nums1[i]<nums2[j])
        {
            v[k++]=nums1[i++];
        }
        else 
        {
            v[k++]=nums2[j++];
        }
    }
    for(;i<m;i++)
    {
        v[k++]=nums1[i];
    }
    for(;j<n;j++)
    {
        v[k++]=nums2[j];
    }
    for(int h=0;h<(m+n);h++)
        nums1[h]=v[h];
  //  return num1;
    }
};
```

Comment: You can't initialize `vector` by indexing like `v[k++]=nums1[i++]`.  You can do it by initializing the vector first like `vector<int> v(size,0)` or you have push( `v.push_back(nums1[i++] `) instead of `v[k++]=nums1[i++]`

Comment: There is probably also an out of bounds array access at `if(nums1[i]<nums2[j])` when one of the indices reaches the limit but the other doesn't.

Comment: I seriously question the value of `m` and `n`. Vectors already have their known size, so we already know how many elements are in `nums1` and `nums2`. What is the point of `m` and `n` ? Also, it *looks* like you were at-one-time returning `v` as your function result. Any reason why you're not now?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `vector<int> v` firstly, since you are accessing an uninitialized vector which has not allocated the store space.

Try to allocate store space with:

```cpp
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(std::max(m,n));
```

or assigning value with:

```cpp
v.push_back(nums1[i++]);
```